# How to get ElasticSearch output?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack

I want to add my log document to ElasticSearch and, then I want to check the document in the ElasticSearch.
Following is the conntent of the log file :

```
Jan  1 06:25:43 mailserver14 postfix/cleanup[21403]: BEF25A72965: message-id=<20130101142543.5828399CCAF@mailserver14.example.com>
Feb  2 06:25:43 mailserver15 postfix/cleanup[21403]: BEF25A72999: message-id=<20130101142543.5828399CCAF@mailserver15.example.com>
Mar  3 06:25:43 mailserver16 postfix/cleanup[21403]: BEF25A72998: message-id=<20130101142543.5828399CCAF@mailserver16.example.com>
```

I am able to run my logstash instance with following logstast configuration file :

```
input {
  file {
    path => "/Myserver/mnt/appln/somefolder/somefolder2/testData/fileValidator-access.LOG"
    start_position => "beginning"
    sincedb_path => "/dev/null"
  }
}

filter {
  grok {
    patterns_dir => ["/Myserver/mnt/appln/somefolder/somefolder2/logstash/pattern"]
    match => { "message" => "%{SYSLOGBASE} %{POSTFIX_QUEUEID:queue_id}: %{GREEDYDATA:syslog_message}" }
  }
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       document_id => "test"
       index => "testindex"
       action => "update"
    }
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I have define my own grok pattern as :

> POSTFIX_QUEUEID [0-9A-F]{10,11}

When I am running the logstash instance, I am successfully sending the data to elasticsearch, which gives following output :[image]

Now, I have got the index stored in elastic search under ***testindex***, but when I am using the `curl -X GET "localhost:9200/testindex"` I am getting following output :

```
{
  "depositorypayin" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : { },
    "settings" : {
      "index" : {
        "creation_date" : "1547795277865",
        "number_of_shards" : "5",
        "number_of_replicas" : "1",
        "uuid" : "5TKW2BfDS66cuoHPe8k5lg",
        "version" : {
          "created" : "6050499"
        },
        "provided_name" : "depositorypayin"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This is not what is stored inside the index.I want to query the document inside the index.Please help. (PS: please forgive me for the typos)

Answer (score 1):

The API you used above only returns information about the index itself (docs [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-get-index.html)). You need to use the [Query DSL](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl.html) to search the documents. The following [Match All Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-all-query.html) will return all the documents in the index `testindex`:

```
curl -X GET "localhost:9200/testindex/_search" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d'
{
    "query": {
        "match_all": {}
    }
}
'
```

Comment: I got this : {"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"skipped":0,"failed":0},"hits":{"total":0,"max_score":null,"hits":[]}}

Comment: [2019-01-18T13:49:04,858][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch] Could not index event to Elasticsearch. {:status=>404, :action=>["update", {:_id=>"test", :_index=>"testindex", :_type=>"doc", :routing=>nil, :_retry_on_conflict=>1}, #<LogStash::Event:0x1b1ee3ed>], :response=>{"update"=>{"_index"=>"testindex", "_type"=>"doc", "_id"=>"test", "status"=>404, "error"=>{"type"=>"document_missing_exception", "reason"=>"[doc][test]: document missing", "index_uuid"=>"SYDH5d8eSUOvsdHbibdxHg", "shard"=>"0", "index"=>"testindex"}}}}

Comment: I am getting the above warning when I am running the logstash, can u help me with this waning, beacuse it says **"reason"=>"[doc][test]: document missing", **

Comment: I'm not very familiar with logstash, but I think you need to add `doc_as_upsert => true` to your output configuration. Otherwise logstash will only attempt to update an existing document, and will not add new documents.

Answer (score 0):

Actually I have edited my config file whic look like this now :

```
input {
. . .
}

filter {
 . . .
}

output{
    elasticsearch{
       hosts => "localhost:9200"
       index => "testindex"
    }

}
```

And now I am able to get fetch the data from elasticSearch using

> curl 'localhost:9200/testindex/_search'

I don't know how it works, but it is now.
can anyone explain why ?

Comment: It works because by removing the `action => "update"` and `document_id => "test"` options logstash will use the default `action => "insert"`. This will cause logstash to add the document to the index instead of trying to update an existing document in the index (which in your case the document did not exist, so it failed).